# Use an empty path parameter in nested Compojure routes

Tags: clojure, compojure

How to match URLs without a trailing backspace in Compojure nested contexts?

Problem I'm trying to solve:

I want to match the following routes:

```
/users/
/users/:user-id
/users/:user-id/resources/
```

The first to access all users,
second for a single user entity,
last for all resources of a given user.

Using the following `defroutes` works:

```lisp
(defroutes
  (GET "/users/" ...)
  (GET "/users/:user-id" ...)
  (GET "/users/:user-id/resources/" ...))
```

However, as my API grow I want to use contexts to clarify the code.

```lisp
(defroutes
  (context "/users"
    (users-routes) ;; All users operations
    (context "/:user-id" [user-id]
      (user-routes user-id) ;; All per-user operations
      (context "/resources" []
        (resources-routes user-id))))) ;; All user - resources operations
```

Which means that `user-routes` should look like:

```lisp
(defn user-routes [user-id]
  (routes
    (GET "" [uid] ...)))
```

Which gives, at compile time:

```lisp
             clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parse error in route string
    data: {:failure
           {:index 0,
            :reason
            [{:tag :regexp, :expecting #"(https?:)?//"}
             {:tag :string, :expecting ":"}
             {:tag :string, :expecting "*"}
             {:tag :regexp, :expecting #"\\."}
             {:tag :regexp, :expecting #"(:[^\p{L}_*{}\\]|[^:*{}\\])+"}],
            :line 1,
            :column 1,
            :text nil}}
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parse error in route string {:failure Parse error at line 1, column 1:
                                         nil
                                         ^
                                         Expected one of:
                                         #"(https?:)?//"
                                         ":"
                                         "*"
                                         #"\\."
                                         #"(:[^\p{L}_*{}\\]|[^:*{}\\])+"
                                         }, compiling:(/Users/laurent/dev/suricate/web/src/web/routes/api.clj:134:5)
```

I believe this is due to the way urls are parsed (with [Clout](https://github.com/weavejester/clout/blob/master/src/clout/core.clj#L56-L69)) hence my question,

What's the correct way to match URLs without a trailing backspace in Compojure nested contexts?

Comment: have you tried `(defn user-routes [user-id] (GET "/" [uid] ...))..`?

Comment: Yep, it works but that's not the REST API I'm working on. I want a clear distinction between entities and "folders". One is an object you can retrieve, the other is a collection you can scan.

Comment: did you ever solve this? same question here!